# Hartshorne exercise III. 3.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As the title implies, I am trying to solve Hartshorne exercise III.3.5.

Here is my idea: if there was an exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_P\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U-P)\rightarrow 0$$
we could take the long exact sequence for $\Gamma$ and since by exercise 3.4 we would have $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_P)=H^1(\mathcal{O}_P)=0$, it would give an isomorphism which would imply the injectivity of the right arrow, which is obviously equivalent to the question.

My problem is that, at least I think, that there is not any such injection $0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_P\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)$. Maybe this can be resolved by choosing some appropriate $\mathfrak{a}$ to take the functors $\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}$? But on the other hand the assumption is about the depth of $\mathcal{O}_P$, not its depth with respect to some specific ideal. Any help?

Comment: Questions here are expected to be self-contained. To that end, please include the text of the problem - this has the added bonus of making your question more likely to get an answer (people who click on it don't have to go get a copy of Hartshorne to know what you're asking, for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should reduce to the case in which $U$ is affine. I can fill in the details here if necessary.

In Exercise III.2.3(e), Hartshorne introduces the long exact sequence in relative cohomology. Taking $Y = P$ and $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{O}_U$, it yields the exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow H^0_P(U, \mathscr{O}_U) \rightarrow H^0(U, \mathscr{O}_U) \rightarrow H^0(U \setminus P, \mathscr{O}_U) \rightarrow H^1_P(U, \mathscr{O}_U) \rightarrow H^1(U, \mathscr{O}_U).
$$
If $U$ is affine, then $H^1(U, \mathscr{O}_U) = 0$ (section III.3). Therefore, the restriction map 
$$H^0(U, \mathscr{O}_U) \rightarrow H^0(U \setminus P, \mathscr{O}_U)$$
is an isomorphism if and only if $H^i_P(U, \mathscr{O}_U) = 0$ for $i \leq 1$. If $U = \text{Spec} \, A$, then 
$$H^i_P(U, \mathscr{O}_U) = H^i_P(\text{Spec}\, A, \tilde{A}) \simeq H^i_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$$
(by 3.3(c) above), where $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$ is the maximal ideal corresponding to the closed point $P$. Therefore, the restriction map of interest is an isomorphism if and only if $H^i_\mathfrak{m}(A) = 0$ for $i \leq 1$. By the exercise 3.4 that you mentioned, the latter condition is equivalent to $\text{depth}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A) \geq 2$.

The last thing to note is that $\text{depth}(A_m) = \text{depth}_{\mathfrak{m}}(A)$. By definition, $\text{depth}(A_\mathfrak{m})$ is the $\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}}$-depth of $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ as a module over itself. Hence, it suffices to show that a sequence $x_1, \dots, x_n \in \mathfrak{m} \subset A$ is regular if and only if its image in $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is regular. If $n=1$, this follows from the fact that $x_1 \in \mathfrak{m}$ is a zerodivisor in $A$ if and only if it is zerodivisor in $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$. The general case can then be deduced by induction on $n$.

Comment: Very detailed and pretty! Thank you very much!